# SSH public key authorization does not work

Tags: ssh, selinux

When logging using public key from client then always password is requested even everything is apparently configured. It's fresh Fedora 24 installation with home disk copied from previous install, access rights to *.ssh/authorized_keys* are correct. *ssh -vvv* does not provide any valuable information.

Surprisingly when sshd started manually as program *sshd -dd* to see log messages then is sometimes works but seems there is a firewall problem or so.

So I edited /etc/sshd/sshd_config enable logging and restarted sshd service.

```
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
#LogLevel INFO
LogLevel VERBOSE

systemctl start sshd
```

After logging attept I inspected log and I see:

```
AVC avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=3111 comm="sshd" name="authorized_keys" dev="sda2" ino=697179 scontext=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:home_root_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
USER_AUTH pid=3111 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=pubkey acct="myname" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=192.168.56.102 terminal=ssh res=failed'
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution at https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=653140 as selinux problem. Problem was probably home copied from another machine.

```
restorecon -R -v ~/.ssh/
```